# Drag and drop OWA mail to add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-app

I want to write a add-in to backup email and attacked file to One Drive for Business server.

But when i try drag and drop email from Outlook Web Application to my add-in, the mouse show not support.

Any idea for me?

1. I try drag and drop email to attacked file when create new mail or reply mail.
   [image: Mail can drag and drop to attacked file when reply or new mail.]
2. I try drag and drop email to my add-in, but not support.
   [image: Mail can't drag and drop to attacked file when reply or new mail.]

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Similar question lead me to this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C

Comment: this link is Winform, i searching Outlook web application add-in :)

Comment: The guide is about finding items ending in .msg, which I believe Office 365 / Outlook Web Access still use, from OS memory, allowing them to be used by any .NET creation. Including Addins.

Comment: i know this. In winform, outlook support drag and drop, but in OWA, when i drag email to my area add-in, it show not support, so i can get any event to read data.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately both the Mailbox API and the JavaScript for Office API do not have any methods or events that facilitate dragging and dropping items in Outlook Online or in the desktop Outlook clients.